# Align multiple images equally in different screen size

Tags: ios, xcode

I am having troubles aligning multiple images by using auto-layout in xcode.
I tried different settings, but nothing seems to work yet (refer to attached photos).

It would be great to hear some opinions from you guys, either in code or storyboard.

I want the image to be aligned equally in different screen sizes.

**Too much space**

[image]

**Last image scaled too much**

[image]

**When Equally width is set**
[image]

**Constraints Setting**
[image]

Comment: You need to set equal widths to all the images.

Comment: it does equally placed the images, but generated an warrning message as follows:

Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
 Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)

Comment: Okay, the constraints you are providing are not enough to satisfy in all the screen sizes . Do you want the UI in landscape as well?

Comment: Fixed some grammar and formatting. Also removed all the irrelevant thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need extra views to achieve this

[image: example]

In the sample picture the red rectangles they are all invisible `UIView` with constraints:

1. fixed length leading space to the view on the left(or the superview)
2. fixed length trailing space to the view on the right(or the superview)
3. fixed length height

This way it's the invisible views who have different width in different screen size while the size of images between them is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

For left most item you should specify `leading space to superview`, for right most specify `trailing space to superview`. For all inner gaps between views specify `horizontal spacing` and for each neighbor view specify `equal width` constraint. Additionally I recommend for you to specify `Align center Y` for all views and set the `y` position constraint only for one of them

Comment: Tried. But all images become very large and overlapped each other.

Comment: @Alvin have you added height constraints?

Comment: Azat...
for left most image view->leading space to superview: done, 
for right most image view-> trailing space to superview: done, 
for all image view-> specify equal width constraint: done, 
for all image view-> add height constraints: done, 

but it doesnt seem to work yet.

Comment: Could you share screenshot what happens with your views in that case?

Comment: i have added a screenshot and corresponding constraints setting

Comment: @Alvin do you want all images to be a square shaped or just have equal widths?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73076/discussion-between-azat-and-alvin).